# How to wait for an index health

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I am using elasticsearch 2.1.2 with Node.js.
I am creating a new index, then I try to search in that index.
But it fails because the index health is red.
I want to wait until the health becomes yellow.

This is the curl API that can be used in this situation.

GET ../_cluster/health/myindex?wait_for_status=yellow&timeout=20s

What is the equivalent API (client method) in Node.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

```
client.cluster.health({
      level: 'indices',
      index: 'myindex',
      requestTimeout: '5s',
      waitForStatus: 'yellow'
    })
```